# How to customize <pagination-controls> color?

Tags: angular, colors, pagination, customization

I am using **angular pagination** and I want to customize this **blue** color into **another** , Can anyone help me.

[image]

I have tried below code stuff also, but it didn't work for me. Below one from this link >>> " https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination"

```
  // head
<style>
  .my-pagination /deep/ .ngx-pagination .current {
    background: red;
  }
</style>

// body
<pagination-controls class="my-pagination"><pagination-controls>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to assign the color for the following selectors

```css
::ng-deep ul > li:not(.active) > a {
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: black !important;
}

::ng-deep ul > li.disabled > span {
  background-color: brown !important;
  border-color: black !important;
}

::ng-deep ul > li.active > a {
  background-color: green !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pagination-emw8qa)

Answer (score 0):

it is really difficult but I managed to change the style of the ngx-pagination library and I explain below how I did it, I hope someone can help you.

HTML and CSS

```css
/* red background at the number*/
.pagination-spreads::ng-deep li {
  background-color: red;
 }

/* I hide the previus when I am at number 1. with ::before */
.pagination-spreads::ng-deep ul > li.disabled {
  display: none !important;
}

/* deactivated numbers will be grayed out */
.pagination-spreads::ng-deep ul > li:not(.active) > a {
  background-color: rgb(142, 142, 142) !important;
  border-color: black !important;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <pagination-controls previousLabel="Prev" nextLabel="Next" (pageChange)="currentPage = $event"
                        class="pagination-spreads">
    </pagination-controls>
</div>
```

This is the result:

[image]